# ggplot2 heatmap total number as Fill value and two

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a table with pokemon data that can be found in Kaggle: [Link](https://www.kaggle.com/code/swashbuckler1/pokemon-exploration-plotly/data)

I'm trying to produce a heatmap using ggplot2 but can't figure out how to use the sum of each pokemon type in each generation as the fill value. The total value should be calculated from two columns, "Type" and "Other Type"

This is what I tried but it doesn't seem to work.

```
ggplot(pokemon_mod, aes(x= Generation, y= Type, z= (Type, Other.Type)) +
  geom_tile()
```

Comment: First, you specify the color of the time with `fill` not `z`. Second, what calculation do you want to perform on the other two columns? You mentioned `sum`? In general it's probably better to do that sort of feature engineering outside ggplot2 (e.g. with `dplyr::mutate()` or `dplyr:: summarize ()`), but you can do some stuff inside the `ggplot()` call depending on how complex it is.

Comment: I added this: 

pokemon_mod %>%
  select(Generation, Type) %>%
  group_by(Generation, Type) %>%
  summarise(count(Type))

The goal is to count the total of each pokemon type for each generation, so it would count the total pokemons of each type for each generation. I can't seem to figure out how to use summarise() for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue in your code is that the color of the tile is specified with the `fill` aesthetic, not `z`. Also in general it's better to do feature engineering outside of ggplot2 and then pass the data in.

Your {dplyr} syntax from the comment is not quite right, but you're close with `count()`.
With `dplyr::count()` you don't need to first `group_by()` so it saves you a step (it's shorthand for `dplyr::group_by(...) %>% dplyr::summarize(count = n())`.

If you want to just combine the counts of `Type` and `Other Type`, you can concatenate into a new column and then use `tidyr::separate_rows()` to essentially append them. Then you just have to remove the `"NA"` values and I think you'll get what you're after:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(vroom)

d <- vroom("pokemon-data.csv") # downloaded from [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/swashbuckler1/pokemon-gen1gen8?resource=download)

d %>% 
  mutate(types = paste(Type, `Other Type`, sep = "_")) %>% 
  separate_rows(types, sep = "_") %>% 
  count(Generation, types) %>% 
  filter(types != "NA") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Generation, types)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = n)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:8)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks! I' curious how would you tackle taking Other Type into account alongside Type?

Comment: What do you want to do with that column? It wasn't clear from your question how you wanted to incorporate it.

Comment: So instead of the count (n) being only based on the column Type, I want it to count from both column Type and Other Type, so even the second type gets mapped. For example in Gen 1 there are no Flying pokemon in Type but there is in Other Type and that's not reflected now. I'm thinking I should elongate the column Type by adding Other Type values below but then I have to do the same for Generation.

Comment: It's not hard to just append `Other Type` to `Type` but then you end up double counting anything that has a value in both columns. Is that what you want? Or do you have some more complex rule you want to apply?

Comment: If by double counting you mean counting both the values in each column then yes